# Separar tabelas em banco para obter os valores de maneira separada

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela com valores a cada mes de vários anos, gostaria de separar cada ano com o respectivo calculo do índice para outra tabela ou fazer as consultas nessa tabela mesmo, como separaria?

```
anomes  indice
201201  0.48
201202  0.48
201203  0.19
201204  0.63
201205  0.39
201206  0.15
201207  0.5
201208  0.45
201209  0.62
201210  0.57
201211  0.51
201212  0.73
201301  0.78
201302  0.61
201303  0.42
```

Comment: Por qual motivo você precisa de diferentes tabelas? Não bastaria selecionar por ano com uma simples cláusula WHERE? Quem sabe uma view para cada ano caso seja imprescindível uma "tabela" diferente para cada ano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa de uma outra tabela, basta fazer uma query para isso, agrupando por ano.

Na sua pergunta não informa qual o banco, para demonstrar vamos supor que seja `mysql`, a query ficaria assim:

```
select substring(ano,1,4) ano,
       sum(indice) soma,
       avg(indice) media
  from teste
 group by substring(ano,1,4);
```

Como também não disse como extamente quer o indice, coloquei na query a soma e média. O resultado dessa query é:

```
| ano      | soma | media    |
| -------- | ---- | -------- |
| 2012     | 5.70 | 0.475000 |
| 2013     | 1.81 | 0.603333 |
```

Pode ver funcionando [no www.db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/a8JeqsP6hbRzaz6U54imbn/0)

Claro que isso pode ser uma View e tratar como se fosse um table, ou ainda pegar esse resultado e criar uma nova table a partir de com `CREATE TABLE SELECT` ou `SELECT INTO`.

Comment: Talvez a questão seja um [problema xy](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy).

Comment: pode ser tbm @anonimo, eu só respondi postando essa solução por causa dessa frase que tem na pergunta *"ou fazer as consultas nessa tabela mesmo"*